# How do you implement multiple simultaneous logins?

Tags: api, rest, restful-authentication

I've built an API, which authenticates requests based on access tokens. These tokens expire in around 30 mins, after which a refresh token has to be sent or the user has to re-authenticate to get a new access token.
I store the tokens in database as below:
user_id | selector | access_token | refresh_token | generated_at
The hashes of the tokens are stored.
So, how do I implement multiple logins?
Do I send the existing tokens to the new device as well or create new tokens and store something like a device id in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be storing any session information in the database. If a client request doesn't have all the information needed to correctly interpret the request, you're not following the stateless constraint, which means you're not doing REST.

The correct way to do it would be for the token itself to have a timestamp or an expiration time. Obviously, that information has to be signed by the server. Take a look at this library for an example on how to do it: http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/

Comment: I never thought about tokens that way. Ended up implementing JWT though. Thanks!

Comment: JWT is perfect for that too. I completely forgot about it.

Comment: Can I use JWT for authorization grant codes(oauth2) or should they be stored in a DB(not stateless) but i need to ensure they are used only once.